# Why these statement are slow in redis?

Tags: redis

I have got following slow query log in redis. I have disable writing to disk. So database is in memory database. I am not able to understand why these two query are slow?

**FYI**
I have total 462698 hash. Having pattern `key:<numeric_number>`

```
 1) 1) (integer) 34
    2) (integer) 1364981115
    3) (integer) 10112
    4) 1) "HMGET"
       2) "key:123"
       3) "is_working"

 6) 1) (integer) 29
    2) (integer) 1364923711
    3) (integer) 87705
    4) 1) "HMSET"
       2) "key:538771"
       3) "status_app"
       4) ".. (122246 more bytes)"
```

Comment: 87 ms for a ginourmous HMSET? Not so bad, I'd say. How many of those do you run each second? And what is overall load?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Only for 1 MB?

Comment: Do you have a very high `hash-max-zipmap-entries` and/or `hash-max-zipmap-value`?

Comment: @Jonatan Hedborg  
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64